# Web Api How to Return Dynamically Created Image and text data simultaneously in same response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I would like to return an image that is dynamically created instead of retrieving from a database or from file. Let's say I have a simple ZipCode class. I would like to have a property that would return an image representation of the zipcode. The JSON returns "ZipAsImage":"System.Drawing.Bitmap".
Yes I am new to the programming in the web world. Yes I have looked for other examples but they seemed to only return an image. Thanks for any help.

```
public class ZipCode
{
    public int ZipCodeId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public Image ZipAsImage
    {
        get
        {
            // Create a blank iamge for now to test.
            return new Bitmap(50, 50);
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

My ApiController class

```
public class ZipCodesController : ApiController
{
    private MyContext db = new MyContext();

    // GET api/ZipCodesController
    public IEnumerable<ZipCode> GetZipCodes()
    {
        return db.zipcodes.AsEnumerable();
    }

    // GET api/ZipCodesController/5
    public ZipCode GetZipCode(int id)
    {
        ZipCode zipcode = db.ZipCodes.Find(id);
        if (zipcode == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
        }

        return zipcode;
    }
...
```

My Controller class

```
public class ZipCodesController : Controller
{
    private MyContext db = new MyContext();

    //
    // GET: /ZipCodes/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var zipcodes = db.ZipCodes.Include(z => z.State);
        return View(zipcodes.ToList());
    }

    //
    // GET: /ZipCodes/Details/5

    public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
    {
        ZipCode zipcode = db.ZipCodes.Find(id);
        if (zipcode == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(zipcode);
    }
...
```

Comment: You need to become familiar with the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace.  If you do not want to get the image from a file or database, then you will have to draw it using code. You can then return it from either an MVC `Controller` or an `ApiController`.

Comment: Hello danludwig, Yes I am familiar with drawing I just put a blank image in for testing. My question is how to return the image with the data of ZipCodeId. How do I modify my GetZipCodes and ActionResult Index routines to do this? Thanks.

Comment: So you want to return binary image content and text data simultaneously, in the same response?

Answer (score 0):

I dont undersatnd the point where you are showing the MVC Contoller.Am i missing something there? However For Webapi (ApiController) You can re write your Method as follows. This should pass the enitre Object in one response.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetZipCode(int id)
{
    ZipCode zipcode = db.ZipCodes.Find(id);
    if (zipcode == null)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,zipcode);
}
```

Sending Binary Images. You need to set Straemcontent and content-type. I found a link that can help you with that [Images with Webapi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491845/asp-net-web-api-downloading-images-as-binary) . Look through the entire thread . You might figure out quickly whats missing...

Comment: My JSON response file shows "ZipAsImage":"System.Drawing.Bitmap". Which of course is the string representation. My current code produces the same. How do I get the binary data instead? Thanks.

Comment: See my edit. I posted a link that might be of some help. There is also a suggestion of using HttpHandler as well .