# Get an image from a method with ActionResult as return type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a Web Api project and I'm getting an image from a controller in a MVC project. The return type is `ActionResult`. The method GetImage in the Web Api has `HttpResponseMessage` as the     return type:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetImage() 
{
    var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    ActionResult image = GetProductImage();
    // ? result.Content = image;
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
    return result;
}
```

Is there a way to put the image from the ActionResult into the HttpResponseMessage?
The code in the other controller looks like this (simplified):

```
public ActionResult GetProductImage()
{
    byte[] bytes = GetImageFromDisk(fullImagePath);
    return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10501073/1184056

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but I have to call the `GetProductImage` method from the other project. There is a lot more going on with the images (crop the image, caching, watermark...). I don't want to rewrite everything. Is there really no way to get the image out of the ActionResult?

Answer (score 0):

```
public HttpResponseMessage Image(int pIndice)
{    
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    using (var binaryReader = new BinaryReader(requestFile[pIndice].InputStream))
    {
        response.Content = new ByteArrayContent(binaryReader.ReadBytes(requestFile[pIndice].ContentLength));
        response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(requestFile[pIndice].ContentType ?? "image/jpeg");
    }
    return response; 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Also, you should try to format your code better.