# Web Api 2 - How to return an image (MemoryStream from Azure Storage) from a HTTPGET without saving to disk?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, http-get, memorystream

I'm using Web Api 2 with C# and Azure, and having issues with how to return the image (base from Memorystream) for displaying on the page...

Here is my Controller HTTPGET

```
[Route("api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/{id}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetPhotoById(int id)
    {
        StorageServices storage = new StorageServices();
        MemoryStream ms = storage.DownloadBlob(id);
        // return what ?
    }
```

Here is the beginning of the servicecall :

```
$http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/' + $routeParams.id,
            accept: 'application/json'
        })
        .success(function(result) {
        // How do i handle the result and what HTML should i use ? <img ?
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP .Net Web API downloading images as binary](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491845/asp-net-web-api-downloading-images-as-binary)

Comment: Thanks for the link :) It might help me a bit, but i still need to figure out how to handle the response on the client : 

string fileName = string.Format("{0}.jpg", id);
    FileStream fileStream = FileProvider.Open(fileName);
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage { Content = new StreamContent(fileStream) };
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = FileProvider.GetLength(fileName);
    return response;

Comment: There's also some reference to a FileProvider which when i google, i only find this : 
http://www.piotrwalat.net/file-download-service-with-resume-support-using-asp-net-web-api/

and that's also using storage to disk it seems ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the client side you don't need to use $http. You can simplify the process by using plain old HTML...

```
<img src="/api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/2232" />
```

For dynamic images use JQuery like this...

```
$('#ImageLocation').html('<img src="/api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/' + intID + '" />');
```

The web browser will automatically do the work of making an HTTP Request for the image, saving you all the complexity.

On the server side, you can use a process like these to load the file and stream it to the client. It's important that the Server code return the correct MIME type such as...

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
```

Resources:

[ASP .Net Web API downloading images as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491845/asp-net-web-api-downloading-images-as-binary/14819168#14819168)

...and...

[Display Image using ashx Handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8733875/display-image-using-ashx-handler)

Comment: I am using web API and oauth, so when I use this `<img src="/api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/2232" />` because token is not set in get request, can you now how can I display image ?

Comment: I'm not sure how you might use oath in this case, it may be possible. What I might do to get it done quick and easy is to bypass oath for that Action using the [AllowAnonymous] attribute, then add a parameter for an auth token... and pass that token via query string.

<img src="/api/PhotoSubmit/GetPhoto/2232?token=SdLK3424ksflS" />

Comment: I know this is old, but this isn't working for me. Could someone provide a more complete example with the appropriate server-side code?